# get the value of alert and post to php

Tags: php, javascript

I have this code below, if i click on the link, the alert (linkhref) will appear, my question is, how to post that (linkhref) on php (sample.php) like $_post[''];

thanks,

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('.linklist').click(function(){    
    var linkhref=$(this).attr('href');
    alert (linkhref);
   $.post("sample.php", { href: linkhref } );

    });
    });
    </script>
```

html:

```
< a href="files/my_file.zip" class="linklist" name="test">test  insert < /a>
```

Answer (score 0):

the line `href: linkhref` in your `$.post()` is the data that is posted to `sample.php`,
in sample.php, just get it as:

```
$href = $_POST['href'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In sample.php you can catch post value of href like this:

```
$linkhref = $_POST['href'];
```